# How to write multiple files in multiple threads, if all file has been written then reschedule timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In windows form C#, I have to write multiple files in multiple threads, if file already exists then overwrite it. After all done then reschedule the time. need help..

```
    public Boolean CreateWriteCSV(string filename,BindingList<Data> data,ItemList us)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            if data!= null)
            {
             //   lock (data)
                {
                    if (data.Count > 0)
                    {
                        String contents = string.Empty;
                        StreamWriter writer;


                        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                        {
                          //  lock (stream)
                            {
                                writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

                                writer.WriteLine(contents.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }));

                                contents = "X,Y,Z"+Environment.NewLine;

                                foreach (Data item in data)
                                {
                                    contents += data.x+","+data.y+","+data.z+ Environment.NewLine;
                                }

                                writer.WriteLine(contents.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }));
                                writer.Flush();
                                stream.Close();

                                ///---check to see file created or not
                                ///
                                us.IsExported = true;

                                lock (parallelThreadList)
                                {
                                    parallelThreadList.Remove(filename);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                   return  true;


                }
            }
            else
            {
                return  false;


            }
        }
        catch
        {
           return  false;
        }           

    }
```

Comment: You introduced us in the goal you want to achieve and shared some code, but it is unclear what problem is blocking you.

Comment: create dedicate thread-safe function `AddCSV(string text)`, prepare text in different threads, call it.

Comment: problem is this one is not writing the all files some files skipped.I am unable to trace....

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes thread behaves strange for some items. Especially while writing files or accessing large data on DataGridView. I use timers on the main thread these times..

For eg:

```
Thread[] thread = new Thread[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    thread[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(writeFile));
    thread[i].start();
}

..
..

void writeFile(string val)
{
    Filestream fs = new Filestream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.write(val);
    sr.close();
    fs.close();
}
```

A thread function can be converted to do in the main thread without interrupting the UserInterface using Timer. This will run the code in the Main thread.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.interval = 5;
List<string> texts = new List<string>();
texts.add(text1);
texts.add(text2);
...
...
timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (texts.count > 0)
    {
        writeFile(texts[0]);
        texts.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    else
        timer.stop();
}
```

some things require the main thread itself to work properly. Like if in the case of DataGridView, when manipulating large data using Threads you can see many datas missing and scrollbars gettin hidden.. Using the main thread will solve the problem..

Answer (score 1):

A situation like missing some files can occur if you use a local variable of the thread and reuse it again before it completes its operation..

```
Thread thread;

void createFilesAsync()
{
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createFile);
    thread.start();
}

createFile(string val)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Doing like this will interupt the thread before completing its operation and recreates another.. In this case the last file of your list will be created without any interruption and some others are created and some not..

Solve this by creating variable within the function.

```
void createFilesAsync()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createFile);
    thread.start();
}

createFile(string val)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```